# Listener for all views

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry for a trivial (i suppose) question, but i have very small experience in programming for ios and in objective-c generally, so i can't figure by myself how to do some method in one place which will be working for all my view controllers (i don't want to multiply code by pasting this method in all my classes). It's a simple method which will connect to server in background thread and receive some data from it. This method is written i just need to figure how to make it work for all view controllers without multiplying code.

Comment: You could put the desired method into an own component (e.g. a class) which will be used by all view controllers. OR: you could write your own view controller, put your method in there and use this base view controller as a base class for all of your other view controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some choices:

- Create a subclass of `UIViewController` and define all your ViewControllers subclasses of your custom class instead of `UIViewController`
- Create a category of `UIViewController` with the implementation of the method
- Create a class with your method declared as a class method:

E.g:
ConnectionManager.h

```
+ (NSArray *) getData;
```

ConnectionManager.m

```
+ (NSArray *) getData{
    //method implementation
}
```

And you can call it from your view controllers like this:

```
[ConnectionManager getData]
```

A variant of this last option is to create a [singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/) object.

Comment: So, it can be done only by using OOP and it's no some mechanism in objective-c to do "when app is running - method is working"?

Comment: What do you mean for "when app is running - method is working"?

Comment: App starts and every 5 minutes (for example) it connects to server (in my case).

Comment: You can implement it in a singleton or in the AppDelegate class. But you have to implement all the logic yourself, there are no Obj-C methods to do this out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very odd to do this "for all view controllers". Connecting to a network to get data would seem to be specific to each view controller to me.

Anyway, you could do something like this in a category.

```
@interface UIViewController (MyDataConnection)

- (void)thisIsYourMethodHere;

@end
```

and...

```
@implemnetation UIViewController (MyDataConnection)

- (void)thisIsYourMethodHere {
    // do your networking stuff here.
}

@end
```

This means that in any view controller you can do...

```
[self thisIsYouMethodHere];
```

And it will run the code in the category.